# Display email and password in Devise confirmation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise-confirmable

By default devise sends this confirmation email:

> Welcome user@email.com!
>
> You can confirm your account email through the link below:
>
> Confirm my account

I'd like it to be:

> Welcome user@email.com!
>
> Email: user@email.com
>
> Password: xxxxxxxxx
>
> You can confirm your account email through the link below:
>
> Confirm my account

How can I set this up in app/views/confirmable/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb? and How can I display the password since it has already been encrypted?

Comment: You should never send user password in plain text in email as it it very insecure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this would be possible, since the password stored in the database would be encrypted by Devise.

In addition you shouldn't want to be e-mailing the user his password in plain-text.

Comment: +1 to this. Do you like people to send your password unencrypted via email when you register to their sites? Neither we do all.

Comment: Yes.. I was thinking about it too. But thats what our marketing department likes. I'll just try to recommend them not to include the password in the email anymore. Hopefully they will agree. ^_^ Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Maybe just show them the site linked below and explain the PR disaster that would occur if accounts were hacked. [Plain Text Offenders](http://plaintextoffenders.com/about/)

Comment: One of my senior devs agreed on this right away. Thanks guys. Sorry I cant vote yet since I have low rep here in stack.